# Vehicle crash Data for all states in USA

Tags: data.gov, api, transportation

Looking to pull as much crash data as available and use it in analytics. Is there any API to pull data directly instead of manually downloading PDF files?

Answer (score 3):

Not aware any API, but these resources aren't PDFs; can most likely scrape/automate accessing these datasets:

[CrashStats - National Center for Statistics and Analysis (NCSA) Motor Vehicle Traffic Crash Data](https://crashstats.nhtsa.dot.gov/#/)
[NHTSA Tool for Querying FARS (Fatality Analysis Reporting System) Data](https://www-fars.nhtsa.dot.gov/QueryTool/QuerySection/Report.aspx)
[Safety Event Mapping Tool](https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/gis/tools/safetyevent/)
[Crashes Time Data (CSV export option)](https://www-fars.nhtsa.dot.gov/Crashes/CrashesTime.aspx)
The above link has more crash data scattered about the domain; look @ the main navigation for relevant links.
[State Traffic Safety Information (STSI)](https://cdan.nhtsa.gov/stsi.htm)